# Parse error in pattern: f . g in fmap (f . g)  = fmap f . fmap g

Tags: haskell

Parse error in pattern: f . g

i am a beginner, where is wrong?

```
   (f . g) x = f (g x)


class Functor f  where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor g  where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 

instance Functor F where
    fmap id = id 
    fmap (f . g)  = fmap f . fmap g
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you make an instance of Functor, you should *prove* the side condition that

```
fmap id = id
```

and

```
fmap (f . g)  = fmap f . fmap g
```

(Technically the latter comes for free given the types involved and the former law, but it is still a good exercise.)

You can't do this just by saying

```
fmap id = id
```

but instead you use this as a reasoning tool -- once you have proven it.

That said, the code that you have written doesn't make sense for a number of reasons.

```
  (f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Since this is indented, I'm somewhat unclear if this is intended to be a definition for (.), but that is already included in the Prelude, so you need not define it again.

```
class Functor f  where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This definition is also provided for you in the Prelude.

```
class Functor g  where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But then you define the class again, but here it has mangled the signature of fmap, which would have to be

```
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> g a -> g b
```

But as you have another definition of Functor right above (and the Prelude has still another, you couldn't get that to compile)

Finally, your

```
instance Functor F where
    fmap id = id 
    fmap (f . g)  = fmap f . fmap g
```

makes up a name `F` for a type that you want to make into an instance of `Functor`, and then tries to give the laws as an implementation, which isn't how it works.

Let us take an example of how it should work.

Consider a very simple functor:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a

instance Functor Pair where
   fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (f b)
```

now, to prove `fmap id = id`, let us consider what `fmap id` and `id` do pointwise:

```
fmap id (Pair a b) = -- by definition
Pair (id a) (id b) = -- by beta reduction
Pair a (id b) = -- by beta reduction
Pair a b

id (Pair a b) = -- by definition
Pair a b
```

So, `fmap id = id` in this particular case.

Then you can check (though technically given the above, you don't have to) that `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`

```
(fmap f . fmap g) (Pair a b) = -- definition of (.)
fmap f (fmap g (Pair a b)) = -- definition of fmap 
fmap f (Pair (g a) (g b)) = -- definition of fmap
Pair (f (g a)) (f (g b))

fmap (f . g) (Pair a b) = -- definition of fmap
Pair ((f . g) a) ((f . g) b) = -- definition of (.)
Pair (f (g a)) ((f . g) b) = -- definition of (.)
Pair (f (g a)) (f (g b))
```

so `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`

Now, you can make function composition into a functor.

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

by partially applying the function arrow constructor.

Note that `a -> b` and `(->) a b` mean the same thing, so when we say

```
instance Functor ((->) e) where
```

the signature of fmap specializes to

```
    fmap {- for (->) e -} :: (a -> b) -> (->) e a -> (->) e b
```

which once you have flipped the arrows around looks like

```
    fmap {- for (->) e -} :: (a -> b) -> (e -> a) -> e -> b
```

but this is just the signature for function composition!

So

```
instance Functor ((->)e) where
    fmap f g x = f (g x)
```

is a perfectly reasonable definition, or even

```
instance Functor ((->)e) where
    fmap = (.)
```

and it actually shows up in [Control.Monad.Instances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html).

So all you need to use it is

```
import Control.Monad.Instances
```

and you don't need to write any code to support this at all and you can use `fmap` as function composition as a special case, so for instance

```
fmap (+1) (*2) 3 = 
((+1) . (*2)) 3 =
((+1) ((*2) 3)) =
((+1) (3 * 2)) = 
3 * 2 + 1 =
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `.` is not a data constructor you cannot use it for pattern matching I believe. As far as I can tell there isn't an easy way to do what you're trying, although I'm pretty new to Haskell as well.

Comment: @Super G: I don't think you can do it.

Comment: how to add a function composition to make f . g work? as above is an example i want to do.

Comment: @Super what you seem to be looking at is something similar to http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Functor These laws are more of documentation than code, saying that Functors are expected to behave a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

`let` is not used for top-level bindings, just do:

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

But the complaint, as cobbal said, is about `fmap (f . g)`, which isn't valid.  Actually, that whole `class Functor F where` is screwy.  The class is already declared, now I think you want to make and `instance`:

```
instance Functor F where
    fmap SomeConstructorForF = ...
    fmap OtherConstructorForF = ...
```

etc.

Comment: without let, will have <interactive>:1:8: parse error on input `='

Comment: @Super G: You can't define classes or instances in GHCi.  You'll get the syntax errors you are.  You need to define them in a file, then :load that file in GHCi.  Of course, you'll run into all kinds of other errors with that code, but that's your fundamental problem here.

Comment: in file i put it at the top. however, Parse error in pattern: f . g, it seems that it do not use the line to do function composition

Comment: Thanks. edit my question again. i really hope to do it. As i have other definition to try.